# JavaScript timer does not continue running on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the script code below, which is working fine on Chrome and Firefox and (when the site has been added to the compatibility mode) in IE. For some reason, if the site has not been added in compatibility view setting, every time the page reloads then so does the timer.  Why is this happening? This does not happen when I run it on my local machine, only when on server.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var intseconds = 0;
        var intminutes = $('#lblTestTime').val();
        //var intminutes = 1;
        //alert(intminutes);
        var inthours = 0;
        var timeString = '';
        var sessionlang = $('#hidElem').text();
        var count = setInterval(function () {



            if ((intseconds == 0) && (intminutes == 0)) {
                intseconds = 0;
                intminutes = 0;
                clearInterval(count);

            }
            else if (intseconds == 0) {
                intseconds = 60;
                intminutes--;
            }

            intseconds--;
            if (intminutes == 0) {
                //inthours--;
                intminutes = 0;
            }
            hours = "0" + inthours + ":";
            if (intminutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + intminutes + ":";
            } else {
                minutes = intminutes + ":";
            }

            if (intseconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + intseconds + "";
            } else {
                seconds = intseconds + "";
            }
            if (intseconds == -1) {
                // code we require
            }
            else {
                timeString = hours + minutes + seconds;

                if (timeString == "00:05:00") {
                    if ($('#MainContent_hidElem').html() == "1") {
                        alert("You have 5 minutes left to complete the test! Please click OK and continue the test.")
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("¡Le quedan 5 minutos para terminar el test! Haga clic en SÍ y continúe el test")
                    }
                }
                $('#dispClock').html(timeString);
                $("#lblRemainingTime").val(timeString);
                //alert($("#lblRemainingTime").val());
                //intseconds = res[1];
                // intminutes = res[2];

            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: _every time the page reloads so does the timer_ - because `$(document).ready(` ... in general, javascript does **NOT** keep running through a page load

Comment: What exactly is the expected behaviour of that code? I don't see any persistance. Are you keeping track of the timer inside the server in the user session? Please check the value of the #lblTestTime comming from the server. I would say that it might not be a problem with this code you have uploaded but with the server's configuration (mutiple nodes? sessión afinity on?)

Comment: Look into [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) in order to save your timers elapsed time. There is no reason to expect that your variables will persist after a page reload.

Comment: but when I add the site to compatibility mode it work fine, so why isnt that the case normally.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in replies, Javascript, by itself, does not store data if you reload the page. When reloading the page, try hitting CTRL+SHIFT+R to force the browser ignore cache.

You could use cookies to store data or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).